# Use unit test or integration test for database or service on iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, testing

As i knew that unit testing not talk to database, not communicate across the network, and not touch the file system.
But problem is: I want to write test case for class that get data from local database or get data from service, how should I write test for these classes? I knew that i can use mock object to simulate data get from local database or service, but with many large database, if we use mock object, we lost a lot of cost to generate mock. So my question is: What is the best approach for test the model to access and retrieve data from local database or from service? use mock for unit testing or use real data for integration test

Answer (score 2):

I would go for testing live/real data for integration tests! I have been doing same thing now. I have three separate testing methods to test my whole system and get more than 90% coverage.

> 1. Unit tests using testing stubs
> 2. Integration tests on live data.
> 3. UI automation using [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF)

All there are going to be integrated in [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) continous integration server

Comment: How do you implement Integration tests on live data?
what tool do you use?